# How to take RGB values and coordinate values in text file?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to write RGB values and coordinate values from RGB image to text file, in the below mention code i am taking values with the help of mouse cursor and trying to save these RGB and coordinate values into text file. But text file is saving only last value of the terminal output.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <fstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
Mat rgb;
char window_name[20]="Pixel Value Demo";

static void onMouse( int event, int i, int j, int f, void* )
{
    ofstream fout("output.txt");
    Vec3b pix=rgb.at<Vec3b>(j,i);
    int Red=rgb.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2];
    int Green= rgb.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1];
    int Blue = rgb.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0];
    int y= rgb.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[3];
    int x = rgb.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[4];
    cout<<"  x= "<<x<<"  y= "<<y<<"  Red="<<Red<<"  Green="<<Green<<"  Blue="<<Blue<<" \t\n";
    fout<<"  x= "<<x<<"  y= "<<y<<"  Red="<<Red<<"  Green="<<Green<<"  Blue="<<Blue<<" \t\n";
    fout<<endl;
    fout.close();
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    namedWindow( window_name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    rgb = imread( "lena.jpg");
    imshow( window_name, rgb );
    setMouseCallback( window_name, onMouse, 0 );
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a new file for every mouse event. Use an ofstream that stays open during the runtime or at least set the mode to append when opening the stream.

E.g.: you could write in your main:

```
ofstream fout("output.txt");
setMouseCallback( window_name, onMouse, &fout );
waitKey(0);
fout.close();
```

And inside the event handler:

```
static void onMouse( int event, int i, int j, int f, void* p){
  ofstream *pfout = (ofstream*) p;
  (*pfout) << "text";
  // do not close file here
```

Comment: can you plz give me an example.

Comment: @Jordan if this answer your question, consider upvoting and marking as the answer.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that?